# Image resizing issues

Tags: wordpress, image, resize

So im building my first wordpress site at the moment. Most problems i come across i just do a google search, read, learn, fix.

But one continuous problem i keep getting is images and resizing them.

Im really lost as to how it works, its so simple, yet i cant seem to manage them at all.

Heres some of my issues:

I'm using customizr theme, it has a slider, featured images for posts-big and small (featured image and thumbnail).

I resize the picture to the recommended dimensions, but it never seems to actually resize the picture in the box. And that's for all of them, the slider, thumbnail and featured image.

I toy with the dimensions to try to learn whats happening, but it just doesn't make sense to me, the box just zooms further into the image, the image doesn't actually move or try to fit at all when the dimensions are changed.

They also share the same image for the featured image and thumbnail, even if i click 'thumbnail only' and change the dimensions, it effects all of the images.

The slider images are always cut off, even if i change to the recommended dimensions. I've given up with the slider after a week of resizing, trying new sliders, adding slider codes into .php, enough.

But now this issue with a simple featured image and thumbnail is the last straw. So here it is, my cry for help!

How can i get control of my images, resize effectively, so i dont get these issues every time i try to add images into various functions.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would start by trying to regenerate the thumbnails https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Also, your image sizes might not have the same aspect ratio as your original uploaded image - check the sizes on how big they are, and if they are hard cropping or soft cropping

Comment: plugin doesnt do anything, just saves a ton of copies with different dimensions somewhere on the computer (unable to find) And yes the dimensions of the original image must be changed to fit into a slider, thumbnail and featured image, ive checked how big they must be, altered them, but nothing changes with the image, just zooms in. As regards to soft or hard cropping, im not sure, but i cant crop the pictures as i made them myself and need 100% of the info to be shown. thanks for the reply though